# Asp.net, Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have drop down 1 in asp.net. I want to populate another drop down 2 based on selected value of drop down 1. how can i achieve this.I don't want to populate from db. I have hardcoded values.

This is my first drop down

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-group" ID="ddl1" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="259px" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this)">
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="All">All</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="ATTOCK">ATTOCK</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="BAHAWALNAGAR">BAHAWALNAGAR</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="BAHAWALPUR">BAHAWALPUR</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

this is my second drop down to populate.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-group" ID="ddl2" Width="259px">
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-1">---All---</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

javascript function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function GetSelectedTextValue(ddl1) {
        var selectedText = ddl1.options[ddl1.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        var selectedValue = ddl1.value;
        alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
      //code to populate ddl2. based on text of ddl1

    }
</script>
```

Comment: they call it a "cascading dropdown" search for that, there are many examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the DropDownList  AutoPostBack="true". So you can add an event for this dropdownlist which will fire during index change and inside that method you can populate second dropdownlist. Like add an event to the first dropdown.

OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed"

If you turn off AutoPostBack, it is then worthy to populate data using JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the options for second dropdownlist using this snippet of code.
Note: First you need jquery (used for simplicity)

```
 function GetSelectedTextValue(ddl1) {
    var selectedText = ddl1.options[ddl1.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var selectedValue = ddl1.value;
    alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
    PopulateDropDown2(selectedText);
}

function PopulateDropdown2(selectedValue) {
    switch(selectedValue) {
        case "All":
            $("#ddl2")
            .html('<option >--Select an Option--</option>' +
                   '<option value="0">My Option 1</option>' + 
                   '<option value="1">My Option 2</option>' +
                   '<option value="2">My Option 3</option>');
            break;
        case "ATTOCK":
            $("#ddl2")
            .html('<option >--Select an Option--</option>' +
                   '<option value="0">My Second Option 1</option>' + 
                   '<option value="1">My Second Option 2</option>' +
                   '<option value="2">My Second Option 3</option>');
            break;
        default:
            $("#ddl2")
            .html('<option >--Select an Option--</option>' +
                   '<option value="0">My Third Option 1</option>' +
                   '<option value="1">My Third Option 2</option>' +
                   '<option value="2">My Third Option 3</option>');
    }
}
```

You can add other options values inside the switch clause and make the code better.

Answer (score 0):

add    `onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this)"`

```
function GetSelectedTextValue(t) {
        vat txt = t.options[t.selectedIndex].text;
        var val = t.value;
        alert("Selected Text: " + txt + " Value: " + val);
      //code to populate ddl2. based on text of ddl1
}
```